# Ellipse distance metric for DBSCAN clustering

Tags: matlab, distance, euclidean-distance, dbscan

I am using the DBSCAN algorithm to determine clusters in a data set obtained by an automotive radar. The paper "Grid-Based DBSCAN for Clustering Extended Objects in Radar Data" from Dominik Kellner, Jens Klappstein and Klaus Dietmayer (link below) proposes a Grid-Based DBSCAN method. Therefore, the search radius *epsilon* variates in azimuth direction depending on the range. The radius in range direction stays constant. The normal DBSCAN is using Euclidean distance metric to determine the *epsilon-neighbourhood* where the search radius is the same in both directions. I cannot find out how to have an ellipse-search instead of a circular.

Do you know a distance metric that is working elliptical? Or, can you provide me with a short code that solves my problem? I am using MATLAB but the code can be in your prefered language.

Let's give an example so we talk about the same:

Consider a cartesian coordinate system with range in meters plotted against azimuth angle in degrees. The search distance in the **range** direction should be **three** meters (or possible observation points) in both directions from a centre point. In **azimuth** direction, the search radius should be **five** points in both directions.

If you cannot think of an elliptical solution, maybe a linear works as well.

Thank you for your help.

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dominik_Kellner2/publication/261127945_Grid-based_DBSCAN_for_clustering_extended_objects_in_radar_data/links/57742a7708aead7ba06e60b5.pdf

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623828/6579744) post DBSCAN is implemented by graph. Use your customized distance matrix for the algorithm.