# Creating Clusters in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

Suppose that I have generated some data in matlab as follows:

```
n = 100;

x = randi(n,[n,1]);
y = rand(n,1);
data = [x y];

plot(x,y,'rx')
axis([0 100 0 1])
```

Now I want to generate an algorithm to classify all these data into some clusters(which are arbitrary) in a way such that a point be a member of a cluster only if the distance between this point and at least one of the members of the cluster be less than 10.How could I generate the code?

Answer (score 3):

The clustering method you are describing is [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). Note that this algorithm will find only one cluster in provided data, since it's very unlikely that there is a point in the dataset so that its distance to **all** other points is **more than** 10.
If this is really what you want, you can use ِ[`DBSCAN`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dbscan.html#mw_36f06016-b3cb-4745-a681-cf8a8fc39e84), or [the one posted in FE](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52905-dbscan-clustering-algorithm), if you are using versions older than 2019a.

```
% Generating random points, almost similar to the data provided by OP 
data = bsxfun(@times, rand(100, 2), [100 1]);
% Adding more random points
for i=1:5
    mu = rand(1, 2)*100 -50;
    A = rand(2)*5;
    sigma = A*A'+eye(2)*(1+rand*2);%[1,1.5;1.5,3];
    data = [data;mvnrnd(mu,sigma,20)];
end
% clustering using DBSCAN, with epsilon = 10, and min-points = 1 as 
idx = DBSCAN(data, 10, 1);
% plotting clusters
numCluster = max(idx);
colors = lines(numCluster);
scatter(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), 30, colors(idx, :), 'filled')
title(['No. of Clusters: ' num2str(numCluster)])
axis equal
```

[image]

The numbers in above figure shows the distance between closest pairs of points in any two different clusters.

Answer (score 2):

The Matlab built-in function `clusterdata()` works well for what you're asking.

Here is how to apply it to your example:

```
% number of points
n = 100; 

% create the data
x = randi(n,[n,1]);
y = rand(n,1);
data = [x y]; 

% the number of clusters you want to create
num_clusters = 5; 

T1 = clusterdata(data,'Criterion','distance',...
'Distance','euclidean',...
'MaxClust', num_clusters)

scatter(x, y, 100, T1,'filled')
```

In this case, I used 5 clusters and used the Euclidean distance to be the metric to group the data points, but you can always change that ([see documentation of `clusterdata()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clusterdata.html))

See the result below for 5 clusters with some random data.

[image]

Note that the data is skewed (`x`-values are from 0 to 100, and `y`-values are from 0 to 1), so the results are also skewed, but you could always normalize your data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using the connected components of graph:

```
D = pdist2(x, y) < 10;
D(1:size(D,1)+1:end) = 0;
G = graph(D);
C = conncomp(G);
```

The connected components is vector that shows the cluster numbers.

- Use [pdist2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to compute distance matrix of `x` and `y`.
- Use the distance matrix to create a logical adjacency matrix that shows two point are neighbors if distance between them is less than `10`.
- Set the diagonal elements of the adjacency matrix to `0` to eliminate self loops.
- Create a [graph](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html) from the adjacency matrix.
- Compute the [connected components](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.conncomp.html) of graph.

- Note that using `pdist2` for large datasets may not be applicable and you need to use other methods to form a sparse adjacency matrix.

I notified after posing my answer the answer provided by @saastn suggested to use `DBSCAN` algorithm that nearly follows the same approach.